# Change default return value of a defaultdict *after* initialization

Tags: python, collections, defaultdict

Is there a way to change the default_factory of a defaultdict (the value which is returned when a non-existent key is called) after it has been created?

For example, when a defaultdict such as

```
d = defaultdict(lambda:1)
```

is created, `d` would return 1 whenever a non-existent key such as `d['absent']` is called. How can this default value been changed to another value (e.g., 2) *after* this initial definition?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assign the new value to the `default_factory` attribute of defaultdict.

[default_factory](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict.default_factory):

> This attribute is used by the `__missing__()` method;
>   it is initialized from the first argument to the constructor, if
>   present, or to `None`, if absent.

**Demo:**

```
>>> dic = defaultdict(lambda:1)
>>> dic[5]
1
>>> dic.default_factory = lambda:2
>>> dic[100]
2
```

Answer (score 2):

Please be careful with `defaultdict.default_factory`, the behaviur could be unexpected.

```
>>> dic = defaultdict(lambda:1)
>>> dic[5]
1
>>> dic.default_factory = lambda:2
>>> dic[5]
1
```

This is because when require `dic[5]`, the missed key is added to the dict with current default value. And modify `dic.default_factory` afterward will not change the value of `5`.